# AngularJS $location service and "Back" button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, current URL is "http://localhost/#/mail". I do some actions, and I want to go to the next url:

```
$location.path("mail/inbox/3")
```

It works good. I'm in another controller with another URL. But when I click by "Back" browser button I hope to be returned to "mail" route, but instead of it I'm gone to "mail/inbox" route. Why? How can I fix it? Because it's incorrect for me. Thanks.

Comment: You sure you are not accidentally navigating to /inbox in between? Because what you are saying doesn't make sense

Comment: No. From "mail" to "mail/inbox/:id" without "mail/inbox"

Comment: could you provide a fiddle to reproduce this issue? i have a similar situation in my app and it works very well

Answer (score 1):

When you fire up this baby:

```
$location.path("mail/inbox/3")
```

Do **remember** that it traversed through `when('mail')` and `when('mail/inbox')` to reach `when('/mail/inbox/:number')`. The route went from `mail -> inbox -> #3`. This is why when you hit back it goes to `mail/inbox`.

This is a messy situation to fix. `ng-router` or `ui-router` are good when thing are simple, but as application grows, bugs like your are unavoidable.

In my projects I disable the `html5Mode` with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`, essentially disabling the back button. And add custom back buttons inside the App for user to navigate back.

This solution helps with:

- User cant use back button at all, so he can't reach an unwanted state
- Custom back buttons can be configured or hidden at times. Event code to preform differently on same view, based on current app state.
- Hide the app internal URL from users to avoid the app being exploited for data the user is not supposed to see.

I hope this helps.